# new data in dataset is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have following code to update chart1 with dataset2 but in the result mychart1 values are not updated to the new values in the dataset2. I want the updated values in dataset2 to be reflected in myChart1, but the old data is getting updated when I look at the class assinged in the debugger.

Can anybody point me where I am going wrong

```
function chart() {

            //Width and height
            var w = 200;
            var h = 100;
            var barPadding = 2;
            var max = 0;

            this.createChart = function(dataset,cls) {

                //create svg element
                var svg = d3.select("#chartDisplay").append("svg").attr("class",cls).attr(
                        "width", w).attr("height", h);

                //create rect bars
                var rect = svg.selectAll("rect").data(dataset,function(d, i) {return d;});

                rect.enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class","original")
                    .attr("x",function(d, i) {
                            return i * (w / dataset.length);
                        })
                    .attr("y", function(d) {
                            return h - d * 3; //Height minus data value
                        })
                    .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
                    .attr("height", function(d) {
                            return d * 3;
                        });

                max = d3.max(dataset);
                var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([ 0, max ]).range(
                        [ 0, w ]);

            }

            this.updateChart = function(dataset,cls) {

                var svg = d3.select("#chartDisplay").select("svg."+cls);

                var rect = svg.selectAll('rect')
                              .data(dataset,function(d, i) {
                                    return d;
                                });

                rect.attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - d * 3; //Height minus data value
                         })
                    .attr("height", function(d) {
                        return d * 3;
                         });   

                rect.attr("class","updated");

            }

            this.getMax = function() {
                return max;
            }

        }

        var dataset1 = [ 5, 10, 12, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13 ];
        var dataset2 = [ 1, 4, 14, 19, 16, 30, 22, 18, 15, 13 ];

        var myChart1 = new chart();
        myChart1.createChart(dataset1,"chart1");
        myChart1.updateChart(dataset2,"chart1");

        var myChart2 = new chart();
        myChart2.createChart(dataset2,"chart2");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll('rect')
              .data(dataset,function(d, i) { return d; });
```

This is telling `d3` to use the data value as a key into your array.  Since your values are changing, the different values don't match and so they aren't being updated (you would need to use another `append` statement to get them to show up).  Since you just have an array of values, you want to use the index of the value as the key (this makes it so that element 1 from dataset1 gets updated with the value of the new element 1 in dataset2).

You can either specifically use the index as the key:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll('rect')
              .data(dataset,function(d, i) { return i; });
```

Or more simply, by doing this since using the index as the key is the default behavior.

```
var rect = svg.selectAll('rect')
              .data(dataset);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The first answer works but I want only the updated rct to change the color but all the rect gets the class updated. Any reason for this behaviour?